# Selecting Various "Pieces" of a List

Tags: python

I have a list of columns in a Pandas DataFrame and looking to create a list of certain columns without manual entry.

My issue is that I am learning and not knowledgable enough yet.

I have tried searching around the internet but nothing was quite my case. I apologize if there is a duplicate.

The list I am trying to cut from looks like this:

`['model',
 'displ',
 'cyl',
 'trans',
 'drive',
 'fuel',
 'veh_class',
 'air_pollution_score',
 'city_mpg',
 'hwy_mpg',
 'cmb_mpg',
 'greenhouse_gas_score',
 'smartway']`

Here is the code that I wrote on my own: `dataframe.columns.tolist()[:6,8:10,11]`

In this case scenario I am trying to select everything but 'air_pollution_score' and 'greenhouse_gas_score'

My ultimate goal is to understand the syntax and how to select pieces of a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do that, or you could just use `drop` to remove the columns you *don't* want:

```
dataframe.drop(['air_pollution_score', 'greenhouse_gas_score'], axis=1).columns
```

Note that you need to specify `axis=1` so that `pandas` knows you want to remove columns, not rows.

Even if you wanted to use `list` syntax, I would say that it's better to use a `list` comprehension instead; something like this:

```
exclude_columns = ['air_pollution_score', 'greenhouse_gas_score']

[col for col in dataframe.columns if col not in exclude_columns]
```

This gets all the columns in the dataframe *unless* they are present in `exclude_columns`.

Comment: And to make the new dataframe with this, it'll be `df[[[col for col in dataframe.columns.tolist() if col not in exclude_columns]]`.

(You can store it into another variable first for brevity.)

Comment: @dTanMan you have one extra set of `[]`.

Comment: @dTanMan thank you for the additional clarification, I have replaced the example with actual dataframe names as followed 
`exclude_columns = ['air_pollution_score','greenhouse_gas_score']

hybrids18[col for col in hybrids18.columns.tolist() if col not in exclude_columns]`

However I am getting an "invalid syntax" that points at "for" what exactly is the first instance of col doing? I am familiar with for loops but have not learned what putting parameters in front of a for loop does?

Comment: and thank you @gmds for your help and thinking differently as I would imagine in this case and others it may be easier to procedurally remove until the dataframe is clean vs. trying to select everything at once.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `df` is your dataframe. You can actually use filters and lambda, though it quickly becomes too long. I present this as a "one-liner" alternative to the answer of @gmds.

```
df[
  list(filter(
    lambda x: ('air_pollution_score' not in x) and ('greenhouse_gas_x' not in x), 
    df.columns.values
  ))
]
```

What's happening here are:

1. `filter` applies a function to a list to only include elements following a defined function/
2. We defined that function using `lambda` to only check if `'air_pollution_score'` or `'greenhouse_gas_x'` are in the list.
3. We're filtering on the `df.columns.values` list; so the resulting list will only retain the elements that weren't the ones we mentioned.
4. We're using the `df[['column1', 'column2']]` syntax, which is "make a new dataframe but only containing the 2 columns I define."

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with pandas

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('path to your csv file')
df = data['column1','column2','column3',....]
```

Note: **data** is your source you have already loaded using pandas, new selected columns will be stored in a new data frame **df**

Comment: The only issue I have with this is that I know I will be working with bigger dataFrames in the future with 40+ columns, in which case this would be SUPER tedious. Thank you for contributing though!